# Emulator for Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense and TinyML

Tags: arduino-nano-ble

I am learning to work with TinyML, and I have Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense board connected to my desktop.

I would like to continue working from my laptop(s) even when I don't have a board with me.

Do you know if there is an emulator for this board that I could use to dome basic programming and exercises?